# Decode JWT encoded string from Google in PHP

Tags: php, google-oauth, jwt

I am upgrading my Google based login system, which requires me to decode `id_token` strings supplied by Google. The strings are valid, and I can decode them via: https://developers.google.com/wallet/digital/docs/jwtdecoder

But I want my server to do this on the fly in PHP.

I found both: https://github.com/firebase/php-jwt/tree/master and https://github.com/luciferous/jwt

But I cannot figure out how to work with PEAR packages. Simple PHP scripts to copy to my server I can do, but I find the documentation given with these 2 packages very limited. Does anybody have sample code on how to decode such a string?

Any help would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understood you correctly, you're trying to decode JWT's with a PHP script?
If so maybe the following PHP code (taken from [https://developers.google.com/wallet/instant-buy/about-jwts#jwt_decoding](http://web.archive.org/web/20150407154128/https://developers.google.com/wallet/instant-buy/about-jwts)) can help you using the script from luciferous.

```
$mwr = array(
  'iat' => $now,
  'exp' => $now + 3600,
  'typ' => 'google/wallet/online/masked/v2/request',
  'aud' => 'Google',
  'iss' => MERCHANT_ID,
  'request'=> array(
    'clientId' =>  CLIENT_ID,
    'merchantName'=> MERCHANT_NAME,
    'origin'=> ORIGIN,
     'pay'=> array (
       'estimatedTotalPrice'=> $estimated_total_price,
       'currencyCode'=> $input['currencyCode'],
      ),
      'ship'=> new stdClass(),
  ),
);
if (isset($input['googleTransactionId'])) {
  $mwr['request']['googleTransactionId'] = $input['googleTransactionId'];
}
WalletUtil::encode_send_jwt($mwr);
```

Comment: Yes exactly. But for such snippet to work, a JWT library has to be installed as far as I know. It's not just uploading the PHP files to the server. Something needs to happen with "composer", which I do not have on my machine it seems.

Comment: The [JWT.php](https://github.com/luciferous/jwt/blob/master/JWT.php) from luciferous's repo should be the only thing you need. Access the decode method of the class with your variables and you should get the correct response as a PHP Object. You don't need pear or composer for the script to work.

Comment: Thank you! I've run the decode function, but I'm getting some errors. Probably due to an incomplete decoding request.

$jwt    The JWT, $key    The secret key. Those 2 values are required. The JWT being the long string. But I am not sure about which secret key they are talking about :s

Comment: When decoding the JWT, both the JWT string but also a "secret key" is required. I am not sure what key to enter? I keep getting these errors: PHP Warning:  openssl_verify(): supplied key param cannot be coerced into a public key in /home/domain.com/php-jwt-master/Authentication/JWT.php on line 179
PHP Fatal error:  Uncaught exception 'DomainException' with message 'OpenSSL unable to verify data: error:0906D06C:PEM routines:PEM_read_bio:no start line' in /home/domain.com/php-jwt-master/Authentication/JWT.php:181

Comment: The key should be your merchant key, you can find instructions [here](https://support.google.com/wallet/business/answer/1387902?hl=en). Also if you don't want to verify your key, you can also pass false to the decode function like so: `JWT::decode($jwt, $key, false)`

Comment: Aaah, i was missing the 'false' parameter. Thanks so much!! Works now :)

Comment: @TheGreenkey thanks a lot! This (https://github.com/luciferous/jwt/blob/master/JWT.php) still works. Using it for my google login integration on my site. Just set the key to null and verify to false as it was not working otherwise